# Running python script using Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to use Process.h library to run a shell command. Here is my code. I am using Arduino Uno.

```
#include <Process.h>
#include <Bridge.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize Bridge
  //Bridge.begin(115200);

  // Initialize Serial
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Wait until a Serial Monitor is connected.
  while (!Serial);

  // run various example processes
  runPythonFunction();
}

void loop() {
  // Do nothing here.
}


void runPythonFunction() {

  Process p;        // Create a process and call it "p"
  //p.begin("/usr/bin/python /home/kairos/Arduino/codes/sketch_jan26a/tweet.py");
  p.runShellCommandAsynchronously("/usr/bin/python -U /path/to/tweet.py");      // Run the process and wait for its termination
  //p.run();
  // Print command output on the SerialUSB.
  // A process output can be read with the stream methods
  while(p.available() > 0) {
     char c = p.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
  // Ensure the last bit of data is sent.
  Serial.flush();
  delay(300000);
}
```

If I do not comment the `Bridge.begin()` line, then in monitor display reverse question marks are displayed. And after commenting that, I am getting some garbage on the serial monitor. Also, my python script makes a new file in the same directory, which runs fine if I run it using a terminal. But if I run it using Arduino code, I am not able to see that new file being generated.

Even using `p.begin()` and `p.run()`it does not run. Nor using `p.runShellCommandAsynchronously()`.

So how can I run that python script?

Comment: Do you have a Yun shield on your Uno?

Comment: I am actually using SparkFun Redboard, same as this https://www.robotshop.com/en/sparkfun-inventors-kit-v40.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIx8S-n9f42AIVS7jACh16PgRVEAQYAyABEgJc5fD_BwE

Comment: Do you have a Yun shield plugged into your SparkFun Redboard?

Comment: No, I have directly connected the board to the computer.

Comment: Was your intention to make your Arduino trigger the execution of a Python script which is on your computer?

Comment: yes, that was what I wanted to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Uno cannot run python.

The Bridge library is intended for communication either between the two MCUs of the Yun, or between an Arduino board and the MCU on a Yun shield.

It is literally a Bridge between the two systems - Arduino and the Linux system in the Yun.

Comment: Is there any way I can run a python script?

Comment: I knew you were going to ask that. Buy a Yun.

Comment: Don't buy a Yún, it is an endless source of troubles. Buy a Raspberry Pi, and you have a full linux operating system for less money.

Comment: Tried it with Rpi, completed it in 20min, the same task that I was trying from two days #hackathon